# Difference between SUM() and COUNT() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was solving this Leetcode question(1173. Immediate Food Delivery I) and I am kinda confused on why I am not getting the right answer when using COUNT(). but when I use SUM(), I am getting the right answer.  I specify a condition for both SUM and COUNT and from my understanding, they should both be adding or counting when order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date, is that mean the condition only working for SUM()?

[image]

**Query that return the right answer(33.33):**

```
select round(sum(order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date)/count(delivery_id)*100,2) as immediate_percentage 
from Delivery
```

**Query that return the wrong answer(100.00)**

```
select round(count(order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date)/count(delivery_id)*100,2) as immediate_percentage 
from Delivery
```

Comment: COUNT() counts, SUM() adds together, just like their names say. If you have 10 rows of data, each one having a column with a value of $10, the COUNT() would be 10  and the SUM() would be $100. Did you try reading the MySQL documentation (which you can find very easily online by searching for *MySQL documentation*)?

Comment: This is standard SQL, not even specific to MySQL. Any SQL tutorial should explain it.

Comment: @KenWhite I am just confused as I specified a condition for COUNT(), so I thought it would only count the row that meets that condition but seems like the condition only work with SUM()?

Comment: I think the difference is  *"...`COUNT(expr)` Returns a count of the number of **non-NULL values** of `expr` in the rows retrieved..."* [see docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count). Since the result of the boolean expression `order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date` is never null, it counts all rows. Whereas `SUM(expr)` returns the sum of `expr`, like the name implies. So when the result is true, `SUM()` adds a `1` to the total. Otherwise it adds 0. That's why the totals are different.

Comment: You can see the difference here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51a59a21488df963ab33f0806fd31eb7

Comment: @SOS Thank you so much for the clear explanation! I now understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically SUM() function [will return the sum of the expression inside of it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) and COUNT() [will returns the number of non-NULL values of elements or rows that the query have returned](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count).

In this case with your query you are looking to get the percentage of the immediate delivery orders so your formula to implement this is `((<numberofimmediate>/<totalamount>)*100)`. At first you can think that `COUNT()` would be the right approach, but that actually will return the complete number of elements in your query so to avoid this we will use `SUM()` to just acumulate the 'ones' that complete the condition ( preferred and estimated are equals so will return 1). If you want to see this in a more visual way you can do:

```
SELECT delivery_id,order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date FROM Delivery
```

This will return the delivery id and 1 if the condition is true but 0 if its false. Then you can use both of functions to see what is the effect on each one:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date) FROM Delivery;
SELECT SUM(order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date) FROM Delivery;
```

`COUNT()`query will return, again, the complete amount of data present in the comparation  (Counting 1 and 0)
`SUM()`query will return the sum of all the values present in the comparation (Adding 1 and 0)

Hope this gives you a better understanding of what's going on with `COUNT` and `SUM` on your queries

You can check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9358ed2fc1dc60422eff0c27355c0f9)

Comment: *"...will return the number of elements or rows that the query have returned..."* More specifically, *"...returns the number of non-NULL values of `expr`..."*. Since the query uses a boolean expression (which never returns null) means all of the rows are counted.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, when you choose Count() it counts how many fields have numbers for example: we have 5 rows, every row has a number (random numbers, let's say 1,2,3,4,5) so the count here will be 5 while the Sum() gives you the sum of variables in this field (in our example: 1+2+3+4+5 = 15).

In the query that gives you the wrong answer, you simply divide count by count (for example 5/5 *100) which will always give you 1.

I hope that you understand

Comment: But I specify a condition for both SUM and COUNT and from my understanding, they should both be adding or counting when order_date=customer_pref_delivery_date, is that mean the condition only working for SUM()?

Comment: As I specified above, Sum adds the variables while Count counts them only so you need both of them to calculate the average and always remember, Sum adds the variable (1+2+...) while count counts them (we have five rows having random numbers so the result is five despite the numbers inside the fields)